# Including Angular configuration Module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have trouble building an Angular module that stores all the configuration data and then including it in my main Angular module.

The idea is for the system to be able to change the configuration data. So the main Module code and controller codes are the same but the config module is different.

I have tried many different way to get this to work but they all give me a series of errors.

My config modules looks like this

```
(function( ){
    angular.module('favoriteeats.config')
    .constant('GLOBAL_CONFIG', {
        'base_uri': '".url( )."'
    });
});
```

My main (condensed) module looks like this. Note I'm using it with a blade template for the brackets.

```
(function( ){   
    var app = angular.module('favoriteeats', ['favoriteeats.config','ngResource'], function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');   
})();
```

My controller looks like this.

```
(function( ){
    var app = angular.module('favoriteeats');
    app.controller('EntrustRolePermissions', function($scope, $controller) {
        angular.extend(this, $controller('BaseController', {$scope: $scope}));
        var vm = this;
        vm.roles = [ ];
        vm.user_roles = [ ];

        vm.updateRoles = function(){
            ret = vm.restApi('role','GET');
            console.log(ret);
        }

        vm.updateRoles( );

    }) //end contoller

})();
```

When I include the config module script in the head I get this error.

"Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module favoriteeats due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module favoriteeats.config due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'favoriteeats.config' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

When I include the config module script in the footer after lazying loading the JS I get the same error.

If I add the config module script to a separate JS file and add this before or after the main module js file I get the same error.

The only way it seem to work is if I included in the same `(function( ){' container as the main module. IE

```
(function( ){
    angular.module('favoriteeats.config')
        .constant('GLOBAL_CONFIG', {
            'base_uri': '".url( )."'
        });

    var app = angular.module('favoriteeats', ['favoriteeats.config','ngResource'], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');   
})();
```

Why is this? How can I extract it and include my config script from another location!?!? I cannot find the answer to determine what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare a module by indicating its dependencies (in this case an empty array) and then you have to execute the function:

```
(function( ){
    angular.module('favoriteeats.config', [])
    .constant('GLOBAL_CONFIG', {
        'base_uri': '".url( )."'
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a faulty IIFE.

```
(function( ){
    angular.module('favoriteeats.config')
    .constant('GLOBAL_CONFIG', {
        'base_uri': '".url( )."'
    });
}); // This does not close the IIFE.
```

Change it to:

```
(function( ){
    angular.module('favoriteeats.config')
    .constant('GLOBAL_CONFIG', {
        'base_uri': '".url( )."'
    });
}()); // or })();
```

*edit;* I didn't even pay attention to the fact that you are not defining your module, but rather referencing it. Like @joao and @mithon suggested - add some brackets:

```
angular.module('favoriteeats.config', [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the 'favoriteeats.config' module instead of defining it. If you add the empty list of dependencies, it should work.

```
angular.module('favoriteeats.config', [])
```